# How can I cancel Ctrl+F in Google Chrome without using the mouse?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Oftentimes, I find myself dealing with a lot of text entry (e-mails, forms, etc.) and accidentally hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> when I mean to type a capital F. This leaves me typing in the **Find on page** box and needing to cancel the Find operation to continue what I was doing.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to cancel the browser's Find function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the <kbd>ESC</kbd> (escape) key, in general that's the type of thing it's intended for. :)

It cancels out and closes the find box for me (in Chrome 39 on Windows).

Comment: If search bar loses focus, ESC won't work - but you can press Ctrl+F again and then ESC